# How to write a loader that depends on some value in another module but still outputs all modules

Tags: webpack

*(I'm using Webpack 3.8.1)*

I have a repo with the code shown in this question:

https://github.com/leoasis/webpack-loader-issue

I'm trying to write a webpack loader that process the contents of the source and generates some value. If the source has dependencies on other resources, I need to load them inside the loader to calculate that value, since it depends on the dependencies' values. To do this I use `this.loadModule` and access the value as soon as the module is loaded.

However, this seems to fail when I have dependencies of the dependencies, as they don't seem to be included in the final bundle, causing an error.

Here's a reduced example to reproduce the case:

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './a.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: './foo-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

// a.js
import './b';
console.log('Hello from a');


// b.js
import './c';
console.log('Hello from b');


// c.js
console.log('Hello from c');
```

And finally, the loader:

```
// foo-loader.js

module.exports = function (content) {
  this.async();
  const dep = content.split('\n')[0].split('\'')[1];
  this._module.someValue = dep.charCodeAt(2); // gets the 'a' from './a'

  if (dep[0] !== '.') {
    this.callback(null, content + 'console.log("the value is", ' + this._module.someValue + ')');
    return;
  }

  this.loadModule(dep, (err, source, sourceMap, module) => {
    if (err) {
      this.callback(err);
      return;
    }

    this._module.someValue += module.someValue;
    console.log(this.resourcePath, this._module.someValue);
    this.callback(null, content + 'console.log("the value is", ' + this._module.someValue + ')');
  });
}
```

This is the resulting bundle:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 1);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
throw new Error("Cannot find module \"./c\"");

console.log('Hello from b');
console.log("the value is", 207)

/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__b__ = __webpack_require__(0);

console.log('Hello from a');
console.log("the value is", 305)

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

Notice how there's an error saying that it can't find module ./c

This works perfectly fine if I changed the loader to be the identity one:

```
  module.exports = function (content) {
      return content;
    }
```

It even fails with a trivial loader that just calls `this.loadModule` and does nothing with the response.

```
module.exports = function (content) {
  const dep = content.split('\n')[0].split('\'')[1];

  if (dep[0] !== '.') {
    return content;
  }

  this.loadModule(dep, () => { console.log('loading', dep); });
  return content;
}
```

Does anybody know what could be going on? Is this an expected behavior of `this.loadModule`? Is this a bug? If it's not a bug, how can I load a module but still make it part of the bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after some research I found this issue https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4959 in the Webpack repo which talks about this same thing. The problem is that `loadModule` does not load modules' dependencies recursively. Ideally this should be supported in the loadModule function in webpack, perhaps with an option in `loadModule`, but for now the work-around is to copy the code that defines the `loadModule` method from Webpack (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/dependencies/LoaderPlugin.js) and change the flag to load modules recursively to true, as in https://github.com/MortenHoustonLudvigsen/ts-css-loader/blob/master/src/loadModuleRecursive.ts.

Basically, change this:

```
compilation.addModuleDependencies(module, [
    [dep]
], true, "lm", false, (err) => {
```

To this:

```
compilation.addModuleDependencies(module, [
    [dep]
], true, "lm", true, (err) => {
```

I'm still not very convinced this solution is the right one, especially since I'm not very familiar with Webpack's codebase, but it works for my use case, so I'll mark it as accepted answer until a better solution appears.